# [Unity]How To Rotate An Object Around Pivot Point

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make an object rotate around a pivot point in the Editor.
I'm using a custom handle (Gizmo for non Unity users) for controlling the pivots rotation, and I found a function that was posted here but it doesn't seem to work the way I need it to.

```c#
 public Vector3 RotatePointAroundPivot(Vector3 point, Vector3 pivot, Vector3 angles)
        {
            Vector3 dir = point - pivot; // get point direction relative to pivot
            dir = Quaternion.Euler(angles) * dir; // rotate it
            point = dir + pivot; // calculate rotated point
            return point; // return it
        }
```

It does rotate the object around the pivot point, but when I rotate the pivot  even just a smidge the object will have rotated around the object a few times, and it will also be in the wrong position for where its rotated.

I know the problem has something to do with the Vector3 angles, but I'm really at a loss for how it needs to be changed.

Comment: Why do something that is already a fundamental part of the _Editor_?

Comment: I know about the pivot button, but is there even a way to change where it pivots from(Other then using the parent)?
Also I'd really like to know the math behind it.

Comment: To rotate an object around an arbitrary point, translate first (the arbitrary offset) then rotate as opposed to rotate-scale-translate

Comment: Try https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I can't figure it out Micky.
And I will Mano thanks, had no idea that existed.